# Appium - Getting Error while taking screenshot with uiautomatorviewer for Instagram story like feature in my app

Tags: android, automation, appium, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

I am automating an app which has Instagram story or WhatsApp status like feature where user upload content and when I am trying to take screenshot I am getting below error.

*Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist!*

I assume content in UI is getting changed too quickly, tool is not able to capture it, can anyone help me capturing screenshot for this page.
Note - Appium server is not running.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()` ?

Comment: I am able to take screenshot now, the stories inside that feature get paused with a tap, so pausing it and now can take screenshot.

Comment: Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Actually was facing issue while taking screenshot with uiautomatorviewer.